# How to create a Hashmap in jasmin?

Tags: jasmin

I want to create a HashMap inside a class in a Jasmin, it's equivalent Java would be :

```
class grammar {
Hashmap <String, Integer> memory= new Hashmap <String, Integer>;
}
```

Something to do with

```
Ljava/util/HashMap
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this homework? Create it in Java, compile to a .class, disassemble the class with `javap` and see the assembly code.